# RandomForestRegressor in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, julia, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to train a `RandomForestRegressor` using [`DecisionTree.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl)
and `RandomizedSearchCV` (contained in [`ScikitLearn.jl`](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl)) in Julia. Primary datasets like `x_train` and `y_train` etc. are [provided in my google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15VcTRfJGsk8YuqqOZ9dpMc198pTK2_tn?usp=sharing) as well, So you can test it on your machine. The code is as follows:

```
using CSV
using DataFrames

using ScikitLearn: fit!, predict
using ScikitLearn.GridSearch: RandomizedSearchCV
using DecisionTree

x = CSV.read("x.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)
x_test = CSV.read("x_test.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)
y_train = CSV.read("y_train.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)

mod = RandomForestRegressor()

param_dist = Dict("n_trees"=>[50 , 100, 200, 300],
                  "max_depth"=> [3, 5, 6 ,8 , 9 ,10])

model = RandomizedSearchCV(mod, param_dist, n_iter=10, cv=5)

fit!(model, Matrix(x), Matrix(DataFrames.dropmissing(y_train)))

predict(x_test)
```

This throws a `MethodError` like this:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fit!(::RandomForestRegressor, ::Matrix{Float64}, ::Matrix{Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.FixedConstant, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\constant_model.jl:26
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.ConstantRegressor, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\constant_model.jl:10
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.LinearRegression, ::AbstractArray{XT}, ::AbstractArray{yT}) where {XT, yT} at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\linear_regression.jl:27
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] _fit!(self::RandomizedSearchCV, X::Matrix{Float64}, y::Matrix{Float64}, parameter_iterable::Vector{Any})
   @ ScikitLearn.Skcore C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\grid_search.jl:332
 [2] fit!(self::RandomizedSearchCV, X::Matrix{Float64}, y::Matrix{Float64})
   @ ScikitLearn.Skcore C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\grid_search.jl:748
 [3] top-level scope
   @ c:\Users\Shayan\Desktop\AUT\Thesis\test.jl:17
```

If you're curious about the shape of the data:

```
julia> size(x)
(1550, 71)

julia> size(y_train)
(1550, 10)
```

How can I solve this problem?

PS: Also I tried:

```
julia> fit!(model, Matrix{Any}(x), Matrix{Any}(DataFrames.dropmissing(y_train)))

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching fit!(::RandomForestRegressor, ::Matrix{Any}, ::Matrix{Any})
Closest candidates are:
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.FixedConstant, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\constant_model.jl:26
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.ConstantRegressor, ::Any, ::Any) at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\constant_model.jl:10
  fit!(::ScikitLearn.Models.LinearRegression, ::AbstractArray{XT}, ::AbstractArray{yT}) where {XT, yT} at C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\models\linear_regression.jl:27
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] _fit!(self::RandomizedSearchCV, X::Matrix{Any}, y::Matrix{Any}, parameter_iterable::Vector{Any})
   @ ScikitLearn.Skcore C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\grid_search.jl:332
 [2] fit!(self::RandomizedSearchCV, X::Matrix{Any}, y::Matrix{Any})
   @ ScikitLearn.Skcore C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\packages\ScikitLearn\ssekP\src\grid_search.jl:748
 [3] top-level scope
   @ c:\Users\Shayan\Desktop\AUT\Thesis\MyWork\Thesis.jl:327
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl/issues/190#issuecomment-1189600120), [`DecisionTree.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaAI/DecisionTree.jl) doesn't support Multi-output RF yet. So I gave up on using `DecisionTree.jl`, And [`ScikitLearn.jl`](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl) is adequate in my case:

```
using ScikitLearn: @sk_import, fit!, predict
@sk_import ensemble: RandomForestRegressor
using ScikitLearn.GridSearch: RandomizedSearchCV
using CSV
using DataFrames


x = CSV.read("x.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)
x_test = CSV.read("x_test.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)
y_train = CSV.read("y_train.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)

x_test = reshape(x_test, 1,length(x_test))

mod = RandomForestRegressor()
param_dist = Dict("n_estimators"=>[50 , 100, 200, 300],
                  "max_depth"=> [3, 5, 6 ,8 , 9 ,10])
model = RandomizedSearchCV(mod, param_dist, n_iter=10, cv=5)

fit!(model, Matrix(x), Matrix(DataFrames.dropmissing(y_train)))

predict(model, x_test)
```

This works fine for me, But it's <del>super</del> slow! <del>**Much slower than Python.**</del>  I'll add the benchmarking with the same data sets across these two languages.

---

## Benchmarking

Here I report the result of benchmarking with the same action, the same values, and the same data. All the data and code files are available in [my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15VcTRfJGsk8YuqqOZ9dpMc198pTK2_tn?usp=sharing). So feel free to test it by yourself. First, I start with Julia.

### Julia

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using ScikitLearn: @sk_import, fit!, predict
@sk_import ensemble: RandomForestRegressor
using ScikitLearn.GridSearch: RandomizedSearchCV
using BenchmarkTools

x = CSV.read("x.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)
y_train = CSV.read("y_train.csv", DataFrames.DataFrame)

mod = RandomForestRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=2)
param_dist = Dict("n_estimators"=>[50 , 100, 200, 300],
                  "max_depth"=> [3, 5, 6 ,8 , 9 ,10])

model = RandomizedSearchCV(mod, param_dist, n_iter=10, cv=5, n_jobs=1)

@btime fit!(model, Matrix(x), Matrix(DataFrames.dropmissing(y_train)))

# 52.123 s (6965 allocations: 44.34 MiB)
```

### Python

```py
>>> import cProfile, pstats
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

>>> x = pd.read_csv("x.csv")
>>> y_train = pd.read_csv("y_train.csv")

>>> mod = RandomForestRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=2)
>>> parameters = {
              'n_estimators': [50 , 100, 200, 300],
              'max_depth': [3, 5, 6 ,8 , 9 ,10]}

>>> model = RandomizedSearchCV(mod, param_distributions=parameters, cv=5, n_iter=10, n_jobs=1)

>>> pr = cProfile.Profile()
>>> pr.enable()
>>> model.fit(x , y_train)
>>> pr.disable()
>>> stats = pstats.Stats(pr).strip_dirs().sort_stats("cumtime")
>>> stats.print_stats(5)

         12097437 function calls (11936452 primitive calls) in 73.452 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 736 to 5 due to restriction <5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   73.445   73.445 _search.py:738(fit)
    102/2    0.027    0.000   73.370   36.685 parallel.py:960(__call__)
12252/152    0.171    0.000   73.364    0.483 parallel.py:798(dispatch_one_batch)
12150/150    0.058    0.000   73.324    0.489 parallel.py:761(_dispatch)
12150/150    0.025    0.000   73.323    0.489 _parallel_backends.py:206(apply_async)
```

So I conclude that Julia performs better than Python in this specific problem in case of speed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Random Forest Regression example docs in DecisionTree.jl, the example doesn't follow the fit!() / predict() design pattern.  The error confirms that fit!() doesn't support RandomForestRegression. Alternatively, you might look at RandomForest.jl package which does follow fit!() / predict() pattern.